# Cannot understand the grammar used in the sentence "I'd love to have lived in the 19th century"

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-perfect, infinitives

I came across this sentence in the one of the English knowledge tests, and it really confused me. It turned out that I cannot say "I'd love to **live** in the 19th century" because of some grammar rules related to the past tense.

I searched about this, but all I got were only more questions and misundestanding.
Some sources said that I can use the "I would have loved" construction, but I'm not sure whether I can use it in this case.

So, which of these examples are correct and what sense do they convey?

1. I would **love** to **have lived** in the 19th century
2. I would **love** to **live** in the 19th century
3. I would **have loved** to **have lived** in the 19th century
4. I would **have loved** to **live** in the 19th century

And what about continuous tense?

5. I would love to **be living** in the 19th century
6. I would love to **have been living** in the 19th century

Comment: I remember having this self-same discussion with _another_ Dennis 30 years ago.  I favor #4, but not sure if there is an actual grammar to cover it. I think you need to think of it as a past wish...otherwise, possibly #1 works, as it describes  a current wish about a past event.

Comment: I've voted to close as this question is more appropriate to English Language Learners.

Comment: I am not in favor of closing this Q...as far as I can see, there is no dupe, and I do not think the Q is  trivial.

Comment: It seems to relate to time travel, which is notoriously difficult when it comes to tenses. Are you saying you would have liked to have been alive then, or that you would like to go to the past and live there, after what you've already lived through in the present?

Comment: 'I'd love to live in the nineteenth century' models on 'I'd love to live on Nineteenth Avenue' and is perfectly grammatical. It is (outside of time-travelling fiction) on the other hand nonsensical ('I'd love to ...' demands a possible, however remotely, scenario) and so unacceptable on other grounds.

Comment: @Cascabel, it wasn't me, because I haven't been here long time :) #4 really seems like a past wish, now I can understand that. #1 also seems for me that I would love to have an experience of living in the 19th century while living in the current time, and I'm trying to comprehend that confusion.

Comment: @Cascabel If this was merely about whether "I'd love to live in the 19th century" is ungrammatical, it should be closed for lack of research, since there's clearly no error in *grammar*. Whether it's what a native/fluent speaker *would* say is debatable, so the question should also be closed as primarily opinion-based. But the OP goes further by providing us with five other sentence constructions and asking us to explain "what sense do they convey?" This, too, is clearly off-topic: the OP should read [ask] and **[this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)**. :-)

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! It seems I'm starting to comprehend something..
And what about examples with continuous tense? It is where I want to emphasize the process of living itself, at some point (or period?) of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of looking at this:

#4 expressing a past irrealis

> I *would have loved* to live in the 19th century

#1 expressing a present wish about a past situation

> I *would love* to have lived in the 19th century

...and  possibly a third suggestion:

#3 expressing a past wish describing the sustained action of living out your years during the 19th century.

> I would have loved to have lived in the 19th century

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am hoping that someone can find a CGEL reference to cover this, but I don't remember one...

Comment: I'll try again. Only to be expected :) _Oh no_, THs Fang and Biggles have disappeared.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am sorry, but I do not understand...I hope you are happy and healthy. I can report that today I got my vaccination, but maybe that is making me a little dizzy and slow.

Comment: I'll let you off. _The Spanish Inquisition_ ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth O crap...yeah I am definitely off-games today. I actually deleted that bit...I thought nobody would get that...

Answer (score 1):

You can't logically say *I'd love to live in the 19th century*, because it makes it sound like a future possibility.

*I would love to have lived in the 19th century* - I would love to have had that experience.

*I would have loved to live in the 19th century* - if I had been alive then I would have
enjoyed the experience.

Since time travel is not a reality, both sentences in effect mean the same.